# How do I unlock more towers and what are their stats?

Tags: pixeljunk-monsters

I recently started playing Pixeljunk Monsters Ultimate, and I've only unlocked the six starter towers so far, but I know there are more. I've created a table for the first six towers, but it would be really helpful to know the stats of the other towers and how to unlock them.

```
Tower     Type    Power   Speed   Range   Spread  Cost    Research Unlock

Arrow     Both    1       1       2       0       100     -        Starter
Cannon    Ground  2       1       1       2       120     -        Starter
Anti-Air  Air     1       3       3       0       150     -        Starter
Tesla     Ground  4       1       1       0       250     10 gems  Starter
Laser     Air     2       1       3       0       300     11 gems  Starter
Mortar    Ground  4       0       3       4       400     15 gems  Starter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally unlocked everything and completed the list.

```
Tower     Type    Power   Speed   Range   Spread  Cost    Research Unlock

Arrow     Both    1       1       2       0       100     -        Starter
Cannon    Ground  2       1       1       2       120     -        Starter
Anti-Air  Air     1       3       3       0       150     -        Starter
Tesla     Ground  4       1       1       0       250     10 gems  Starter
Laser     Air     2       1       3       0       300     11 gems  Starter
Mortar    Ground  4       0       3       4       400     15 gems  Starter
Fire      Ground  4       1       2       3       350     13 gems  Tiki S2
Frost     Ground  1       1       2       3       200     -        Tiki S3
Trap      Both    5       0       0       1       250     10 gems  Gati Gati S1
Hive      Both    1       2       5       0       450     14 gems  Gati Gati S2
Gem       None    0       0       1       0       300      9 gems  Tiki S1
Lightning Both    1       0       5       3       500     13 gems  Tiki S2
```

Notes:

- Fire towers continually fire at the same spot for a set duration, dealing damage over time. Enemies with green shields are weak to flame towers and burning enemies are resistant to them.
- Frost towers don't deal any damage, but do slow enemies down. They can remove the burning effect from burning enemies.
- Trap towers consist of both a tower and an antenna, which must be near each other with no obstructions between them. Two traps are strung between the towers, one that hits ground enemies and one that hits air enemies. Each trap causes an explosion when triggered and can only trigger once per wave.
- Hive towers generate insects over time. Each insect will roam the map, smash into the first enemy that gets in its way, and then disappear. You can only have one hive tower at a time.
- Gem towers do not attack. They slowly upgrade any adjacent towers around them over time. Each gem tower has limited energy, and cannot be removed even after that energy is depleted.
- Lightning towers hit every enemy on the map, but only attack when enemies are near them.

In addition to towers, you can also unlock

- Speed Potion

  - Makes TikiMan run faster. This is a permanent upgrade.
  - Unlock by completing Tiki S1
- Remote Mine

  - Allows you to set a remote mine at TikiMan's location for 5 gems at any time, and detonate at will. You can only have one mine set at a time. These deal high damage over a decent range, hitting both ground and air enemies.
  - Unlock by completing Gati Gati S3
- Interest

  - Increases the amount of gold acquired at the end of each wave by 5% per tier. Each tier costs more gems than the last.
  - Unlock by completing Toki S3

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot [here](http://wikicheats.gametrailers.com/PixelJunk_Monsters_-_PS3/Towers). Not how to unlock for all tower though.

These are the 4 towers you miss:

```
Tower     Type    Power   Speed   Range   Spread  Cost    Unlock                          Research

Ice       Ground  1       1       2       1       200     Beat Tiki island Special 3      9 gems
Fire      Ground  4       1       2       3       350     Beat Tiki island Special 2      13 gems
Hive      Both    1       2       5       0       450     Beat Gati Gati island Special 2 14 gems
Lightning Both    1       1       5       3       500     Beat Toki island Special 2      13 gems
```

and unlocks for some more: (no stats for now)

- Speed Potion - Beat Tiki island Special 1
- Remote Mine (Bomb) - Beat Gati Gati island Special 3
- Gem Tower - Beat Toki island Special 1
- Interest - Beat Toki island Special 3

Comment: Thanks. For the "Unlock"  column I was actually looking for which stage you have to beat to unlock them, but I had forgotten to include the research cost. Edit: I added a column for research cost to my table.

Comment: I just unlocked the Fire tower from completing Tiki Island Special 2. The source you linked seems to be missing the Trap Tower, Gem Tower, and Land Mine (and possibly more, but those are the ones I saw from some Googling).

Comment: Added the unlock thingies. I don't play the game myself, so I didn't knew I missed some tower. Strange.